# Angular code unable to find $resourceProvider

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to retrieve a JSON array from a file Json.json located in the same folder as my js code. And I am getting this error:

Error: Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- members <- jsonservice

My code is as following:

```
angular.module('rdfa',[]).config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {controller: RdfaCtrl});
}])
.factory('members', function($resource){
    return $resource('Json.json', {}, { query: {method:'GET', params:{File:'Json'},       isArray:true} });
})
.service('jsonservice',function(members){
    this.events=members.query();
});
function RdfaCtrl($scope,jsonservice){
    $scope.members=jsonservice.events;
}
```

Please anyone help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include angular-resource.js and specify it as a dependency in your angular.module invocation:

```
angular.module('rdfa',['ngResource']).config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {controller: RdfaCtrl});
}])
.factory('members', function($resource){
  return $resource('Json.json', {}, { query: {method:'GET', params:{File:'Json'},       isArray:true} });
})
```

See this [plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/83WiADg9JKJjzLpGHarH/index.html)